# Highchart multiple-color line series dynamically

Tags: c#, highcharts

I am making a line chart using highchart and i want to try to make different color on it.

Let me show you my current code :

I have 6 arrays:

```
var xAxes = ['2021-05-05','2021-05-06','2021-05-07','2021-05-08','2021-05-09']
var Min = [2,2,2,2,2]
var Max = [200,200,200,200,200]
var value = [100,134,156,133,26]
var judge = ['OK','NG','OK','OK','NG']
var boxNo = ['Box1','Box1','Box1','Box2','Box2']
```

And here is my code for creating the chart :

```
$('#container5').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: 'x'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Daily IC Log Data'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Running Date'
            },
            xAxis: {
                tickInterval: 150,
                categories: xAxes,
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    turboThreshold: 1000000
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                shared: true,
                headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y} us<br/>'
            },
            series: [
                {

                    name: 'Value',
                    data: value,
                    type: 'spline',
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'Minimun Std',
                    data: Min,
                    color: 'red',
                    type: 'spline',
                    line: {
                        dashStyle: 'longdash'
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'Maximum Std',
                    data: Max,
                    type: 'spline',
                    tooltip: {
                        valueDecimals: 2
                    }
                }              
            ]
        });
```

From my code above, I want to make differential on my line chart based on `boxNo`.
The line color on chart should be different based on `boxNo`. Is it possible?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try something based on your code to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function to generate zones for a series based on the `boxNo` array. Example:

```
var colorsMap = {
    Box1: ['blue', 'red', 'black'],
    Box2: ['green', 'yellow', 'orange']
};

function getZonesForSeries(seriesIndex) {
    var currentZone;
    var zones = [];

    boxNo.forEach(function(bN, index) {
        if (bN !== currentZone) {
            currentZone = bN;

            if (zones.length) {
                zones[zones.length - 1].value = index;
            }

            zones.push({
                color: colorsMap[bN][seriesIndex]
            });
        }
    });

    return zones;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t8hcab7d/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.zones

Comment: do you know how to improve highchart rendering line series with zones's performance? Because based on your reference code, I've already succeed to update in my own code. But my chart has n point which changed dynamically. Once user query for more than 10.000 points, the browser's loading is taking so long time. Is there another method to make it faster ?

Comment: Hi @tryingtocode, Sorry for the late replay! You can try to use `multicolor_series` plugin: http://blacklabel.github.io/multicolor_series/